# How to disable autoHide of resizeable of jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do i disable autoHide with a click after i create a resizeable with

```
.resizable({
            autoHide:true
 })
```

tried

```
.click(function(){
            $(this).resizable("option",{autoHide:false});
        });
```

but not working

http://jsfiddle.net/u9nEc/8/

Comment: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is reported bug of the jQueryUI Resizible the only thing you can really do is to make some hack or patch. I propose this little workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/u9nEc/10/